# What does the term "input-synchronized calls" mean?

Tags: multithreading, apartments

I found this in an article on Multithreaded Apartments, but can’t find a definition for “input-synchronized calls”.
(Article is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693421(VS.85).aspx)

As used in the article 
- Multithreaded apartments cannot make input-synchronized calls

What are “input-synchronized" calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693770(VS.85).aspx).

> Input-synchronized calls - When making
>   input-synchronized calls, the object
>   called must complete the call before
>   yielding control. This helps ensure
>   that focus management works correctly
>   and that data entered by the user is
>   processed appropriately. These calls
>   are made by COM through the Windows
>   SendMessage function, without entering
>   a modal loop. While processing an
>   input-synchronized call, the object
>   called must not call any function or
>   method (including synchronous methods)
>   that might yield control.